# Autocomplete field with overlay text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, textfield, overlay

I have created a autocomplete text field in flutter, but i want to add feature where there is overlay text to predict the suggestion. I put the image for reference

I expecting to create a autocomplete text field with overlay text behind it for suggestion

[I want to create like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30t2D.png)

Comment: Take a look at this:  https://pub.dev/packages/multi_trigger_autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You should try [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) Package, it have similar functionality.

Comment: i had tried it but still can't find how to create like image in my attachment, any example?